# Input string was not in correct format | decimal/integer to "NULL"

Tags: vb.net, null, decimal

I've recently started learning .net and I wrote a basic sql connected data entry form. Almost all of my data types are integer or decimals. Sometimes I need to remain empty the textboxes and enter "NULL" data and I receive with this error "Input string was not in correct format".

How I can fix this error ? Key point; I don't want to enter "0" it must be "NULL" in sql server because I use some charts to track all of these data, so when there is data equal the "0" its ruined my charts. As far as I understand from my researches Tryparse is fit for it but I couldn't find any information to use it properly in .net.

I'll share my transformation code below.

```
Try
    Dim command As New SqlCommand()

    command.Parameters.Add("A", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Decimal.Parse(A)
    command.Parameters.Add("B", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Integer.Parse(B)
    command.Parameters.Add("C", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Decimal.Parse(C)
    command.Parameters.Add("D", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Decimal.Parse(D)
    command.Parameters.Add("E", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Decimal.Parse(E)
    command.Parameters.Add("F", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Decimal.Parse(F)
    command.Parameters.Add("G", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Integer.Parse(G)
    command.Parameters.Add("H", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Integer.Parse(H)

    c.CUD(command, sql)
    list()
    clear()
    MessageBox.Show("Data Successfully Saved")

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Why you have to enter `"NULL"` in the TextBoxes at al? If it's empty it should be enough. When you send it to the database you have to assign `DBNull.Value`. It's easy with `double.TryParse` to validate the input

Comment: You should use `TryParse` to validate the data but, if it fails, you should tell the user to fix the input. By the time you get to the point of running the code you posted here, you should already know that all the input is valid. You can handle the `Validating` event of each control and validate the input there. That way, the input will be validated as the user enters it, rather than waiting until they've populated all the fields incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
command.Parameters.Add("strokeTB", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = If(strokeTB.TextLength = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), Decimal.Parse(strokeTB.Text))
```

This assumes that you have already validated the contents of the `TextBox` and it is guaranteed to either be empty or contain a valid `Decimal` value.

This `If` operator is similar to the old `IIf` function but it's better because it short-circuits, i.e. the third argument operand is only evaluated if the first operand is `False`. Because `IIf` is a function, it evaluates all three arguments first, so `Decimal.Parse` would still be called and it would fail. Using `If`, `Decimal.Parse` will only be called if there is text to parse.

Comment: Or possibly you could TryParse the contents and respond to that evaluation result?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer, I would do that at an earlier stage. If you were to use `TryParse` here then you'd end up saving `NULL` when the user entered invalid data rather than telling them to fix it.

Comment: @John your method works well, thank you very much. Now I have one more issue; when I double click the data from datagridview, textboxes fill with the entered datas but if there is NULL data I receive this error: "Conversion from type DBNull to type String is not valid." How I can fix this?

Comment: @marcy, that is not directly related to the question you have asked here. If you have another issue then you should post another question, providing ALL and ONLY the information relevant to that issue.

Comment: @John ok. thank you I'll post new question.